Powerapps button and text label
In Powerapps, I have a button with some text in it. I want to add a text label as well (this way to have a smaller font). How can I add a text label over a button and be visible but the user can still click the button. I’m worried the user will click over the text label and it’ll block the button. Is this possible? Thanks!

You're right, if the label is on top of the button, clicks on the label will not go to the button. But you can tell it to do so - by using the Select function in the label's OnSelect property to call the same property of the button, as shown below:


or, you can make your button transparent and send it back, below of the button
